# insert element on array on private function

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

How can insert element into final position of array this array is on a private function??

```
private function getData()
{

    return array(
            1 => array(
                    'open_cookie_id' => 1,
                    'text' => 'I may throw up on ya',
                    'who'  => 'Leonard McCoy',
            ),
            2 => array(
                    'open_cookie_id' => 2,
                    'text' => 'I think these things are pretty safe.',
                    'who' => 'James T. Kirk'
            ),
            3 => array(
                    'open_cookie_id' => 3,
                    'text' => 'Well, I hate to break this to you, but Starfleet operates in space.',
                    'who' => 'James T. Kirk'
            ),
            4 => array(
                    'open_cookie_id' => 4,
                    'text' => 'Yeah. Well, I got nowhere else to go. The ex-wife took the whole damn planet in the divorce. All I got left is my bones.',
                    'who' => 'Leonard McCoy'
            ),
            5 => array(
                    'open_cookie_id' => 5,
                    'text' => 'If you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.',
                    'who' => 'Spock'
            )
    );

}
```

How to insert the element 6 , 7, 8 etc to final array on these function private from other function
from this function:

```
  /**
     * Create a resource
     *
     * @param  mixed $data
     * @return ApiProblem|mixed
     */
    public function create($data)
    {
        //return new ApiProblem(405, 'The POST method has not been defined');
        //return $this->create($data) ;
        $adapter = new ArrayAdapter($this->getData());
        $adapter2 = Array
        (
            $data->open_cookie_id => array(
                                    'open_cookie_id'=>$data->open_cookie_id ,
                                    'text' =>$data->text, 
                                    'who' => $data->who
                                        )
        );

        $adapter2_converted = new ArrayAdapter($adapter2);
        //operation for merge two ArayAdapter ($adapter+$adapter2_convert)
       // $collection = new OpenCookieCollection($final_adapter);
        //return $collection;
    }
```

I'm using php zend framework and apigility.

Answer (score 3):

The `function` is **private** not the `array` so you can safely work with your returned `array`. Do notice that `$adapter` is a `ArrayAdapter` data type, not a simple `array` so you can't simple push.

My suggestion is to add a method to your `ArrayAdapter` that uses PHP `array_push()` to add your array to your `ArrayAdapter` data structure and use like this:
`$adapter->pushArray($adapter2);`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the line where you're actually calling the private method `getData()`:

```
$adapter = new ArrayAdapter($this->getData());
```

If all you need as a result is an array with some extra elements added to it, you can do something like this:

```
$data = $this->getData();
$data[] = 'more data';
$data[] = 'even more data';
$adapter = new ArrayAdapter($data);
```